# Weird Phaser black lines and "blur" while moving

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

(called it "blur" because i dont know how it is really named)
Footage: https://youtu.be/zvoQilhFxUw
Project: https://github.com/hasezoey/phaser-tiled-test/

Does anyone know why its happening and how to fix it?

Phaser 3.8
Tileset tiles 16x16 (no spaceing / margin)
Map made with Tiled
Vivaldi@latest

Black Line / Bleeding Fix: https://github.com/sporadic-labs/tile-extruder
Fixed by [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50432202/wierd-phaser-black-lines-while-moving-problems/50439253#50439253)

EDIT: when changing pixelArt to false, it works fine but seems washed-out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the tileset needs extruding to avoid the bleeding in WebGL. This node app should do exactly what you need: http://phaser.io/news/2018/05/webgl-tile-extruder

Comment: yes the black line problem got fixed by  https://github.com/sporadic-labs/tile-extruder, but the other thing this blur (should be seeable in the video) is still there